# Sampling and matching samples with spatial conditions

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

## The Problem

I have two tables with start points of a route and possible end points of a route which need to be matched against each other. I also have a given distribution for the distance between this points.

- 38% of the routes are between 2 and 5km
- 24% between 5 and 10km
- 18% between 10 and 25km
- 12% between 25 and 50km
- 8% between 50 and 140km

In Total I have 17 million start and an 17 million end points which need to be matched. A Point belongs to a geometry which is identified by its `rs` (regional key). If a point was matched it is marked as used.

## The Current State

When I match the points I do run 8 python processes running the Query below

### System Information

- `SELECT Version();` PostgreSQL 9.5devel on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (Gentoo 4.8.3 p1.1, pie-0.5.9) 4.8.3, 64-bit
- EXPLAIN ANALYSE: http://explain.depesz.com/s/MAY
- XEON 1231v3, 16 GB Ram, Samsung 840 PRO SSD
- Changes to the default postgresql.conf

```
# Connection 
listen_addresses = '*' 
max_connections = 16 

# Logging 
log_destination = 'csvlog' 
log_directory = 'pg_log' 
logging_collector = on 
log_filename = 'postgres-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' 
log_rotation_age = 1d 
log_rotation_size = 1GB 
log_min_duration_statement = 500ms 
#log_checkpoints = on 
#log_connections = on 
#log_disconnections = on 
log_lock_waits = on 
#log_temp_files = 0 

# Memory 
shared_buffers = 1GB 
temp_buffers = 32MB 
work_mem = 512  MB 
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB 
effective_cache_size = 8GB 

# Checkpoint ( When to write to disk ) 
wal_buffers = 16MB 
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9 
checkpoint_timeout = 30min 
checkpoint_segments = 32 
random_page_cost = 1.1 

fsync = off 
synchronous_commit = off 
full_page_writes = off
```

### Table layout

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE de_sim_points_start
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('de_sim_points_id_seq'::regclass),
  rs character varying(12),
  used boolean DEFAULT false,
  lookup integer,
  geom geometry(Point,25832),
  CONSTRAINT de_sim_points_start_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) INHERITS (de_sim_points);

CREATE INDEX de_sim_points_start_geom_idx ON public.de_sim_points_start USING gist(geom) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100);
ALTER TABLE public.de_sim_points_start CLUSTER ON de_sim_points_start_geom_idx;
CREATE INDEX de_sim_points_start_lookup_idx ON public.de_sim_points_start USING btree(lookup) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100);
CREATE INDEX de_sim_points_start_rs_geom_idx ON public.de_sim_points_start USING gist(rs COLLATE pg_catalog."default", geom) WHERE NOT used;
CREATE INDEX de_sim_points_start_rs_idx ON public.de_sim_points_start USING btree(rs COLLATE pg_catalog."default") WITH (FILLFACTOR=100);
CREATE INDEX de_sim_points_start_rs_used_idx ON public.de_sim_points_start USING btree(rs COLLATE pg_catalog."default", used DESC);
CREATE INDEX de_sim_points_start_used_idx ON public.de_sim_points_start USING btree(used) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100);
```

### The Query

I have a somewhat working query which looks like this and performs like this http://explain.depesz.com/s/MAY. With somewhat working I mean, that it does only matches a subset of the requested amount of points that should have been matched. For Example the Query below matched 165 points insted of the requested 235, but for bigger cities like Hamburg it would be around 50000-80000 points to match. Currently I kinda work around this by executing the Query 3 times and hoping that the matches go up.

Also as said before I have distributions, so in order to lower the complexity and amount of points for the bigger distances I first do the matching of the points for the lower distances and then try to match the bigger once.

```
WITH 
    reachable as (
      SELECT sk.rs 
      FROM de_commuter_kreise ck 
        INNER JOIN de_shp_kreise sk ON sk.rs=ck.rs AND ST_DWithin(
            (SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM de_shp_kreise WHERE rs = '066340003003')
            , sk.geom
            , 140000) 
      UNION 
      SELECT cg.rs 
      FROM de_commuter_gemeinden cg 
        INNER JOIN de_shp_gemeinden sg ON sg.rs=cg.rs AND ST_DWithin(
            (SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM de_shp_gemeinden WHERE rs = '066340003003')
            , sg.geom
            , 140000)
    ),
    points AS (
    SELECT s.id AS start, e.id AS destination, ST_Distance(s.geom, e.geom) AS distance_meter 
    FROM (
          SELECT id, geom, row_number() over() as i 
          FROM (
                 SELECT id, geom
                 FROM de_sim_points_start
                 WHERE NOT used AND rs = '066340003003'
                 ORDER BY RANDOM() 
                 LIMIT 235 
                 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
               ) AS sq
          ) AS s 
    INNER JOIN (
          SELECT id, geom, row_number() over() as i 
          FROM (
                SELECT id, geom
                FROM de_sim_points_end 
                WHERE NOT used AND rs IN (
                  SELECT * FROM reachable
                )
                ORDER BY RANDOM()
                LIMIT 235 
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
              ) AS t
          ) AS e USING(i) 
    WHERE NOT ST_DWithin(s.geom, e.geom, 50000) 
          AND ST_DWithin(s.geom, e.geom, 140000)
    ),
    upsert_start AS (UPDATE de_sim_points_start ps SET used = true FROM points p WHERE p.start = ps.id), 
    upsert_destination AS (UPDATE de_sim_points_end pe SET used = true FROM points p WHERE p.destination = pe.id) 
INSERT INTO de_sim_routes_outgoing (start_point, end_point, distance_meter)
SELECT start, destination, distance_meter FROM points;
```

### The Problem of the Query

The biggest problem of the query is the ORDER BY RANDOM() as you can see in the EXPLAIN ANALYSE I posted. So the most optimization potential probably lies here.

## Possible Solutions

### Not using ORDER BY Random()

When I do not use ORDER BY Random() the Query runs decently fast, BUT of course the rows are not random anymore as the selected rows are now biased towards the first found once. So this is not really an option since they should be randomly matched.

### Sampling using index scans

I found some posts on the internet explaining how index scans can be used to sample random rows.

- http://explainextended.com/2009/07/18/postgresql-8-4-sampling-random-rows/

I tried to adopt this to my problem which looks like this and has this execution plan http://explain.depesz.com/s/xd7.

```
WITH  RECURSIVE q AS (
  SELECT  r, minid, maxid, ARRAY[(r).id] AS bt, 1 AS cnt
  FROM    (
    SELECT  rm.*,
      (
      SELECT  r
      FROM    de_sim_points_start r
      WHERE   id >= (minid + FLOOR((maxid - minid) * RANDOM()))::INTEGER
      ORDER BY
        id
      LIMIT 1
      ) r
    FROM    (
      SELECT  MIN(id) AS minid, MAX(id) AS maxid
      FROM    de_sim_points_start
      WHERE NOT used AND rs = '066340003003'
      ) rm
    ) ro
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  ri, minid, maxid, bt || (ri).id, cnt + 1
  FROM    (
    SELECT  q.*,
      (
      SELECT  ri
      FROM    (
        SELECT  ri
        FROM    de_sim_points_start ri
        WHERE   id >= (minid + FLOOR((maxid - minid) * rnd))::INTEGER
          AND NOT bt @> ARRAY[id]
        ORDER BY
          id
        LIMIT 1
        ) r
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  ri
      FROM    (
        SELECT  ri
        FROM    de_sim_points_start ri
        WHERE   NOT bt @> ARRAY[id]
        LIMIT 1
        ) r
      LIMIT 1
      ) ri
    FROM    (
      SELECT  q.*, RANDOM() AS rnd
      FROM    q
      ) q
    ) qo
    WHERE   cnt < 235 AND ri IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT  (r).id
FROM    q;
```

I guess my indexes are just not right.

- https://www.periscope.io/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster.html

## Question

Is there a way to maximize the precision, meaing the amount of matched points with one execution is as high as possible, while reducing the overall execution time?

Comment: I'd select the points each query instance should work with into exclusive sets before running the matching in parallel. In a separate query. Otherwise the queries spend an unknown amount of time fighting against each other for locking the same rows.

Comment: Since I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 which has a Rowlevel locking the paralellism is not a problem and does work decently.